# Designing a regular expression to exclude non-ASCII

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regular expression in my program pre-database insert that stops certain characters getting through. I need to alter it to stop non-ASCII also.

The existing regex is:

```
Regex.IsMatch(fieldValue, @"^[\p{L}\p{M}' \.\-]+$")
```

Comment: If you 'stop Unicode', you'll be left with no characters at all. What do you actually want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(fieldValue, "[^\x20-\x7E]"))
            return fieldValue;
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could ignore character range above ASCII

`[^\\u007f-\\uffff]`

Comment: This will match multiple bytes for combining characters. In practice you'd want to keep the non-combined part (i.e. the ascii character without the diacritics), or be able to replace a 'disallowed' character by a _single_ replacement character, not potentially a number of replacement characters in a row. Do you have ideas on how to get that behaviour?

Comment: Indeed. I did not consider that. Perhaps you could use the AsciiEncoding class?

edit: or use System.Globalization.TextElementEnumerator to split out non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I have already implemented a method that removes diacritics, I just want to return false if it contains anything outside of Ascii

Comment: In that case, I'll +1 this answer, beause I think it fits the goal

Comment: Then it's outside my knowledge of regular expressions. Perhaps you could just look for them manually using TextElementEnumerator.

Comment: For me, this didn't work? E.g. The string 'SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyy' didn't get through